# Area of effect attacks: roll once per attack or one per victim?

Tags: savage-worlds

If a grenade or a Blast affects two zombies, three werewolves, and their evil leader (a WC), how many times do I roll for damage?

The Savage Worlds Deluxe on p70 says that: "Everything under (or partially under) the template is affected, rolling damage separately for each Wild Card or group of Extras". This suggests I roll three times.

However, the [FAQ](http://savagepedia.wikispaces.com/Damage+Rules+FAQ) state that you must "Roll the damage once and apply to each target separately". This suggests I roll once.

I have searched on StackExchange and the official forum but could not find an answer to this question. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 6):

I asked [in the official forum](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=391262#391262) and the answer is: you roll once per group of extras and once per wild card.

> The rulebook is correct, **roll three times**.
>
> To clarify, Savagepedia is  "The Unofficial Savage
>   Worlds Wiki" and is handled by fans not Pinnacle. Also note, that FAQ
>   specifically says it is for "Savage Worlds Revised" which is an older
>   edition of the rules than SW Deluxe.

Update: As @Phil notes, the term 'group of extras' is flexible and not necessarily restricted to 'groups made by common type', as my question seems to imply.

Comment: Note that the definition of a 'group of Extras' can be flexible. If a grenade landed and hit a mass of 12 soldier Extras, I would probably split them into 3 or 4 groups for the purposes of determining damage. Otherwise a single damage roll would either wipe out the whole lot or none of them.

Comment: Very good point! I am adding it to my answer. :-)

Comment: @Phil, good point, though 12 soldiers packed that close are very vulnerable to a grenade going off.  It wouldn't be unreasonable to assume one grenade incapacitated a dozen soldiers.